# Why are gnome apps not respecting button-layout?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, compiz, xfce, window-buttons

Working with Ubuntu Studio (XFCE desktop) 18.04.  I'm seeing this problem:   [image: image of example problem child window]

What's happening is that I'm setting the `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences.button-layout` setting in dconf-editor to put all my window buttons on the *left* side.  dconf-editor (and other I'm assuming GTKish applets) are putting the buttons on the *right* side.  I'm running metacity/compiz as my WM, and don't know what setting I'm missing (or if I'm missing any).

Does anyone know the setting I'm missing?  This isn't happening on my laptop with a 17.10 install with the same config.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot a `:`. Try

```
'appmenu,shade,maximize,close:'
```

Comment: @pomsky Thanks for the style edit—I don't use SE sites much.  Tried the setting with the colon—didn't help with gnome core apps, which I found out use client-side decorations; CSDs in the gnome core apps apparently don't respect the setting as I found in [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/how-to-switch-window-controls-to-the-left-gnome-shell#answer-353846).  Should we close the question?

Comment: @HenryGernhardt Hmm... I'm not completely about the incompatibility with CSD though, works fine in my case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE7Ic.png

Comment: I'm perplexed, then.  I can't move my CSD window buttons in either my 17.10 or my 18.04 install.  In the 17.10 install, the CSD window buttons are on the left as desired, but neither the 18.04 nor the 17.10 install respect the setting (i.e. they don't move, and they give me minimize rather than shade).  Are you using the stock WM?  I switched mine out to metacity/compiz, and I wonder if maybe that interaction is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Gnome 3 client side decorations.  I discovered the culprit in [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/how-to-switch-window-controls-to-the-left-gnome-shell/353846#353846).  Further research revealed [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961161/how-do-i-disable-client-side-decoration-globally-in-gnome).  The solution turned out to be:

- Install the `gtk3-nocsd`package (available in the universe repository)
- log out, then log back in

This results in a hackish but functional means by which to restore the title bar and remove the CSD window buttons.