# Title bar is not appearing in gnome Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: titlebar

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 but Title bar which used to show File Edit etc is not appearing like it used to show in unity.

[image: see_screnshot_of_the_problem]

Comment: Could you add some details? maybe a screenshot would also help

Comment: that is the default behavior in Ubuntu 18.04 for nautilus/files. Other apps may show if Alt key is pressed.

Comment: Because of [Client-Side Decoration (CSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-Side_Decoration).

Comment: @pomsky what should I do to have title bar.pressing alt is not working.

Comment: You can try using `gtk3-nocsd` package (refer to [answers here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961161/how-do-i-disable-client-side-decoration-globally-in-gnome)), but not sure how successful that would be.

Answer (score 2):

Many applications move towards eliminating the classical menu. Files, the standard file manager of the Gnome Desktop in Ubuntu 18.04, is among these apps. You will find the options under various buttons in the top bar. Application wide menus are found in the drop down menu in the top bar. You open that menu by clicking on the application name in the top bar. (This appmenu will disappear in the near future in future Gnome versions)][1](https://blogs.gnome.org/aday/2018/10/09/farewell-application-menus/).