# How to move window button position

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, window-manager

While I working on some pdf file, I've found the window button (Maximize, Minimize, Close) has a bad position, they're in line with pdf tools button.

[image: ugly window button :(]
This seems had to do with the fact that I used Lubuntu, in which Lubuntu uses Openbox window manager, whereas Evince uses GTK (CMIIW). I try installed Okular, and it seemed to do fine without problem.

How do I make it look like this—if possible?

[image: desired]

Comment: Some clarifications, please. What is CMIIW? Is your problem with Evince? Evince, I assume is using "client-side decorations" and so its buttons will be drawn by Evince itself and not the window manager of your OS. Okular does not use CSD and so, its buttons are placed by the window manager.

Comment: Thanks ! I followed your suggestion about CSD, and discovered a package called `gtk3-nocsd`, it fixes the problem that bugging me since installing Lubuntu. Thanks ! You're a lifesaver :D

Comment: @DKBose your method looks as answer, consider to write it this way :)

Comment: @N0rbert, I posted an answer and linked to a related question. [One answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/999663/248158) there has fewer votes but is better, IMO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A related question is [How do I disable client side decoration globally in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/q/961161/248158) and one answer refers to using [gtk3-nocsd](https://askubuntu.com/a/999663/248158).

*gtk3-nocsd* is in the repositories and can be installed using `sudo apt install gtk3-nocsd`. Logging out and logging back in is needed to enable it.

The present question refers to Evince which is an application using [client-side decorations (CSD)](https://blogs.gnome.org/tbernard/2018/01/26/csd-initiative/) by default. After enabling *gtk3-nocsd* and logging out and logging in, the maximize, minimize, and close buttons are still in the top-right corner.

However, Lubuntu has the *obconf* package that allows the user to alter what appears in a window's title bar, assuming CSD has been disabled.

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `obconf` will launch the *Openbox Configuration Manager*. The *Appearance* tab allows the user to move the maximize, minimize, and close buttons to the top-left corner of the title bar by changing the original order from "NLIMC" to "CIMLN" or whatever the user desires.

[image: obconf]

The image below shows both *PCManFM* (foreground) and Evince (background) with the buttons on the left.

Just for completeness, *Okular* is a *qt*-based application and currently doesn't apply CSD. And [here](https://pointieststick.com/2019/03/06/more-on-headerbars-rebuttals/) are a KDE member's thoughts on the matter.

[image: After changing order of title bar components]